# Visual Studio + GIT commit woes

Tags: git, scom

I've been using Visual Studio to create small projects, creating Management Packs for Microsoft System Center Operations Manager (SCOM). For a long time we used TFS to centralise any changes to the projects but have recently moved to GIT.

All has been fine until recently when I need to add a new solution + projects to the existing set. I copied the projects (the framework of which is created outside of Visual Studio) into the GIT repository and then opened it from Visual Studio, added it to Source (at which point, for some reason it warned me that it contained source data that was outside of the repository) and commited the changes. Then I synched those changes to a remote GIT Repo. Since then however, EVERY existing project and solution now is in the list of excluded changes, and all projects have a red tick, suggesting there are changes to commit. I committed and synched one of these as a test, and sure enough, it did an equal number of deletes and creates for that solution / project, essentially just overwriting itself, with itself.

What could have happened? And how can I troubleshoot this before things get in a total mess? Tempted to just blow way my local repo and sync down from the remote repo?

Comment: can you post contents of .gitignore file?

Comment: You shouldn't need to add the new projects to source. You should only need to commit the new files thru the Team Explorer -> Changes panel.

Comment: I think I used "Add Solution to Source Control" which was a hangover from the process I would use with TFS. Unable to post the contents of the GITIGNORE file as it's too much text for the form here. Is there something specific I'm looking for?

Excerpt:
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
build/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

# Roslyn cache directories
*.ide/